# On linux, what can cause dlopen to emit SIGFPE?

Tags: linux, dlopen, sigfpe

I have a library of dubious origins which is identified by `file` as a 32 bit executable.  However, when I try to `dlopen` it on a 32 bit CentOS 4.4 machine, dlopen terminates with `SIGFPE`.  Surely if there was something wrong with the format of the binary then `dlopen` should be handling an error?

So the question is: What kinds of problems can cause dlopen to emit SIGFPE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some possible reasons are:

1. Division by zero (rule this out with gdb)
2. Architecture mismatch (did you compile the DSO yourself on the same architecture? or is it prebuilt?)
3. ABI compatibility problems (loading a DSO built for one Linux distro on a different one).

[Here](http://fixunix.com/unix/379047-fpe-ld-linux-x86-64-so-loading-custome-dso-apache.html) is an interesting discussion regarding hash generation in the ELF format in GNU systems where an ABI mismatch can cause SIGFPE on systems when you mix and match DSOs not built on that distro/system.

Run GDB against your executable with:

```
]$ gdb ./my_executable
(gdb) run
```

When the program crashes, get a backtrace with

```
(gdb) bt
```

If the stack ends in `do_lookup_x ()` then you likely have the same problem and should ensure your DSO is correct for the system you are trying to load it on ... However you do say it has **dubious origins** so the problem is probably an ABI problem similar to the one described.

Get a non-dubious library / executable! ;)

**Good Luck**

Comment: Great link, thank you.

My issue was that the library had been cross-compiled on a 64 bit RHEL5 machine and I was trying to run on a 32 bit RHEL4 machine.  The magic trick was to use "-m32 -Wl,--hash-style=both" when rebuilding the library on the RHEL 5 machine.